# Como evitar Inserts Simultaneos

Tags: php, sql-server

Em um sistema de venda realizo um `INSERT` cadastrando a capa do pedido (pedido sem os itens) logo depois do cadastro da capa realizo um `SELECT MAX` para me retornar o ultimo id inserido para utilizar esse id como foreign key na inserção dos itens na tabela itens.

```
INSERT INTO CAPAPEDIDO VALUES (123,GETDATE());

SELECT MAX(CodPedido) AS LastID FROM CAPAPEDIDO;

INSERT INTO PEDIDO_ITEM(CodPedido,CodProduto,Qtd,VrUnit,TotItem) VALUES ($lastId ,$codProduto,$qtdProduto,$valorProduto,$totItem);
```

esse é exemplificado o processo que eu uso.
a duvida é se houver vários pedidos acontecendo de forma simultânea haveria conflito no LastId no 2 `SELECT MAX`? os itens poderia ser cadastrados em outra capa de pedido?
pensando em mais de 3.000 pedidos ao mesmo tempo.

qual seria a solução?

ajuda ai! obrigado

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paulo, o que você questiona realmente pode ocorrer e é devido à [concorrência de processos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorr%C3%AAncia_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Em SQL Server há algumas soluções; uma delas envolve o uso da função [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql):

```
-- código #1
declare @LastID __;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT into CAPAPEDIDO (col1, col2) values (123, current_timestamp);
set @LastID= scope_identity();

INSERT into PEDIDO_ITEM (CodPedido, CodProduto, Qtd, VrUnit, TotItem) 
     values (@LastId, $codProduto, $qtdProduto, $valorProduto, $totItem); 

COMMIT;
```